# setting and checking a 32 bit variable

Tags: c++, c

I am wondering if setting a 32 bit variable after checking it will be faster than just setting it? E.g. variable a is of uint32

```
if( a != 0)
{
    a = 0;
}
```

or

```
a = 0;
```

The code will be running in a loop which it will run many times so I want to reduce the time to run the code.
Note variable a will be 0 most of the time, so the question can possibly be shortened to if it is faster to check a 32 bit variable or to set it. Thank you in advance!

edit: Thank you all who commented on the question, I have created a for loop and tested both assigning and if-ing for 100 thousand times. It turns out assigning is faster.(54ms for if-ing and 44ms for assigning)

Comment: Have you tried measuring it yet? What's the result? (I'm assuming you did profiling already, so you're sure you should care at all about this question - right? ;) )

Comment: You'll almost always be better of just doing the assignment without the test first.

Comment: Premature optimization is the best optimization, am I right?

Comment: You should have measured before asking. Not just the two operations themselves but the relative impact on your application.

Comment: If it is faster, the compiler will insert the test for you

Comment: Branch instructions are bad [citation required]. `if` statements require branch instructions (except on processors that implement conditional assignments). Ergo, `if` statements are bad (except when they're not). In other words, just write the code without the `if`, and when you've got it all working, add the `if` and measure.

Comment: @M.M Surprisingly, one does not get optimized to the other. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0910b95cc7f516e7 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94dbf4fe36e4f328

Comment: @BaummitAugen lol, wonder if it's worth reporting a missed-optimization bug.

Comment: Thank you all who commented on the question, I have created a for loop  and tested both assigning and if-ing for 100 thousand times. It turns out assigning is faster.(54ms for if-ing and 44ms for assigning)

Comment: @J.Chen  Suggest appending your test comment to the post as the are key to the question - or post it as your own answer.

Comment: If you are always writing the same variable, you will only be dirtying one cache line. Not much win.  Any benefit comes when there are many different cache lines that may or may not be dirtied.   //. This shows how hard it can be to make good measurements, and how easy to measure the wrong thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you describe is called a "silent store" optimization.

PRO: unnecessary stores are avoided.

This can reduce pressure on the store to load forwarding buffers, a component of a modern out-of-order CPU that is quite expensive in hardware, and, as a result, is often undersized, and therefore a performance bottleneck. On Intel x86 CPUs there are performance Event Monitoring counters (EMON) that you can use to investigate whether this is a problem in your program.

Interestingly, it can also reduce the number of loads that your program does. First, SW: if the stores are not eliminated, the compiler may be unable to prove that the do not  write to the memory occupied by a different variable, the so-called address and pointer disambiguation problem, so the compiler may generate unnecessary reloads of such possibly but not actually conflicting memory locations. Eliminate the stores, some of these loDs may also be eliminated. Second, HW: most modern CPUs have store to load dependency predictors: fewer stores increase accuracy. If a dependency is predicted, the load may actually not be performed by hardware, and maybe converted into a register to register move. This was the subject of the recent patent lawsuits that the University of Wisconsin asserted against Intel and Apple, with awards exceeding hundreds of millions of dollars.

But the most important Reason to eliminate the unnecessary stores is to avoid unnecessarily dirtying the cache. A dirty cache line eventually has to be written to memory, even if unchanged.  Wasting power. In many systems it will eventually be written to flash or SSD, wasting power and consuming the limited write cycles of the device.

These considerations have motivated academic research in silent stores, such as http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.28.8947&rep=rep1&type=pdf. However, a quick google scholar search shows these papers are mainly 2000-2004, and I am aware of no modern CPUs implementing true silent store elimination - actually having hardware read the old value. I suspect, however, that this lack of deployment of silent stores us mainly because CPU design went on pause for more than a decade, as focus changed from desktop PCs to cell phones. Now that cell phones are almost caught up to the sophistication of 2000-era desktop CPUs, it may arise again.

CON: Eliminating the silent store in software takes more instructions. Worse, it takes a branch. If the branch is not very predictable, the resulting branch mispredictions will consume any savings. Some machines have instructions that allow you to eliminate such stores without a branch: eg Intel's LRBNI vector store instructions with a conditional vector mask. I believe AVX has these instructions. If you or your compiler can use such instructions, then the cost is just the load of the old value and a vector compare  if the old value is already in a register, then just the compare.

By the way, you can get some benefit without completely eliminating the store, but by redirecting it to a safe address. Instead if

If a[i] != 0 then a[i] := 0

Do

ptr = a+I; if *ptr == 0 then ptr.:= &safe; *ptr:=0

Still doing the store, but not dirtying so many cache lines. I have used this way if faking a conditional store instruction a lot. It is very unlikely that a compiler will do this sort of optimization.

So, unfortunately, the answer is "it depends".  If you are on a vector mask machine or a GPU, and the silent stores are very common, like, more than 30%, worth thinking about. If in scalar code, probably need more like 90% silent.

Ideally, measure it yourself. Although it can be hard to make realistic measurements.

I would start with what is probably the best case for thus optimization:

char a[1024*1024*1024]; // zero filled
const int cachelinesize = 64;
for(char*p=a; p

Every store is eliminated here - mAke sure that the compiler still emits them. Good branch prediction, etc

If this limit case shows no benefit, your realistic code is unlikely to.

Come to think if it, I ran such a benchmark back in the last century.  The silent store code was 2x faster, since totally memory bound, and the silent stores generate no dirty cache lines on a write back cache. Recheck thus, and then try on more realistic workload.

But first, measure whether you are memory bottlenecked or not.

---

By the way: if hardware implementations of silent store elimination become common, then you will never want to do it in software.

But at the moment I am aware of no hardware implementations of silent store elimination in commercially available CPUs.

As ECC becomes more common, silent store elimination becomes almost free - since you have to read the old bytes anyway to recalculate ECC in many cases.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed answer, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @JChen: I ignored your question when I first it, thinking "Isn't it obvious, the smaller code is the better".   But then I realized that it was the SW version of something that is on the edge of implementation in HW - and that I had recommended a version of this for "performance programming" on supercomputers in the Intel Optimization Guide.  //  I.e. I think that it is not the sort of thing that a beginner should worry about, but it is the sort of thing that an expert performance analyst will have in their toolbox.

Comment: Usually "measure first", but unless your code has a hotspot standard tools may not indicate that there is an opportunity for this optimization.  E.g. the performance cost of unnecessary dirtying occurs much later, not at the instructions in question.  EMON events indicating bus bound, with lots of dirty writebacks, are indicative. // But certainly "measure on a microbenchmark first", to see if it matters for your hardware.  It wont always - although the microbenchmarks that many other posters have provided are useless for testing this.

Comment: Oh, and while I was taught in school "most programs have a hotspot that you can optimize", by the time a program gets to an expert performance analysis most of the easy hotspots have gone away.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment would do you better as firstly the `if` statement is redundant and it would make it clearer if you omitted it, also the assignment only should be faster and even if you are not quite sure of it you can just create a simple function to test it with and without the `if` statement.